# what will happen when a field is marked as both Shared and Unversioned

Tags: templates

If I check both shared and unversioned checkboxes in a template, what will happen?
I knew difference between shared and unversioned. Want to know final result of checking both field in template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared will get priority since it covered all versinos in all languages, rather than only versions of a given language happen by Unversioned

Comment: then what is the use of checking two check boxes?

Comment: There is no use of setting both checkboxes.

Comment: It's basically terrible UX in the Content Editor. There should be a drop-down with a single choice like Sitecore Rocks; or a radio-set; or it should automatically de-select "Unversioned" if you select "Shared".

Answer (score 16):

In reality, you have only 3 options. However the combination of checkboxes gives you 4.

## The Answer

### A versioned field (default)

This acts like one would expect. The field can have multiple values and multiple versions of a value; for multiple languages.

### The Unversioned Field

Essentially this field gets 1 version *per language*, so the designation "Unversioned" is a little misleading. However there will be only 1 version of the field per language, not multiple versions within a language.

### The Shared Field

Only one version of this field exists, across language versions.

This leaves out the last combination:

### The Shared Unversioned Field

Now one could argue; that in theory it could make sense to have multiple versions of a shared field, but then have the field value propagate across language versions.

However, on a Data Provider level this just isn't possible. There are also areas of the Sitecore UI that would make this approach unworkable.

To find out why, I refer you to Yan Sklyarenko's post [Back to Basics: Versioned, Unversioned and Shared Fields](http://sklyarenko.net/blog/2010/09/10/back-to-basics-versioned-unversioned/), where he explains that field values in Sitecore is essentially stored in one of 3 different tables:

- VersionedFields
- UnversionedFields
- SharedFields

When selecting field values, Sitecore executes a JOIN statement across these 3. A field value will therefore only be selected from 1 of the above.

This is also reflected in the UI of [Sitecore Rocks](http://vsplugins.sitecore.net/), where this setting is presented as a Dropdown choice.

[image]

**Shared is therefore a superset of Unversioned**

## So to answer your question:

*Setting both boxes will make your field be **Shared**. Unversioned is ignored.*

## Additional reading:

- http://www.kewlcodes.com/posts/1159/Versioned-vs-Shared-vs-Unversioned-fields-in-Sitecore
- http://ysdevlog.blogspot.ch/2010/09/back-to-basics-versioned-unversioned.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893888/in-sitecore-when-adding-a-field-to-a-template-theres-a-checkbox-called-share
- http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/changing_field_sharing_settings_in_sitecore/

This last article describes the processes that happen *under the hood* in Sitecore, when you check and uncheck these boxes. A data migration process essentially takes place, moving field values around between the 3 above mentioned tables.